# Есть ли разница между "следующим" и "следующим за"

Tags: синтаксис

Возникло непонимание, пожалуйста рассудите.

"1, 2, 3".

В моём понимании, 1 следует за 2, получается 2 *следующий*, а 1 *следующий за ней*. Также получается, что 1 и 2 являются следующими за 3.

Является ли моё понимание верным?

Answer (score 1):

Ваше понимание неверно. Согласно словарному определению, следующий - это "ближайший **после** кого-нибудь, чего-нибудь". В вашем примере цифра 1 стоит **перед** цифрой 2, а не **после**. Соответственно, назвать эту цифру "следующей" за 2 или 3 ни в каком контексте нельзя.

Comment: Ответ поддержал, но *никогда не говори никогда* :) Это я насчёт "ни в каком контексте". Пример контекста: "при прочтении справа налево ..." (учитывая, что нам неизвестно, какой язык родной для автора вопроса, это не совсем шутка)

Comment: Ведь разве 1 не следует за 2?

Comment: @grizzly, что-то я тоже не могу придумать контекст, в котором можно будет сказать, что цифра 1 следует за цифрой 2. при прочтение справа налево, можно будет сказать, что цифра 1 предшествует цифре 2. Но никак не следует.

Comment: @grizzly, да, но все же это это ресурс по русскому языку, так что исходить нужно из чтения слева направо.

Comment: @Серж Пусть на доске написана строка "1 | 2 | 3". Я бы сказал, что при прочтении этой строки слева направо цифра 1 предшествует цифре 2, а при прочтении той же строки справа налево цифра 1 следует за цифрой 2. Неужели Вы бы сказали иначе?

Comment: Да, только предшествует. Не могу сказать иначе. Потому что она в любом случае стоит перед цифрой 1.